# select text from table1 using words in other table2

Tags: sqlite, sql-like

I am trying to select text from table 1 using words in other table 2. I searched on the site and found this solution:

```
select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.text like '%'+table2.word+'%';
```

I tried it but it did not gave me any result, but if I search any word manually it finds results.

for example i have this text in table 1

Just think, If Arsenal signed **Mata** we'd now be title contenders just like Man United.

and in table 2 i have the word "**Mata**" and other fields,,, i tried and nothing appear

Comment: Works for me. Show some example values that you think should match.

Comment: Does it work with a subselect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, strings are concatenated with the `||` operator:

```
... table1.text LIKE '%' || table2.word || '%'
```

`+` is used to add numbers; applying it to other strings would result in zero.